# Continously insert arduino serial data in mysql using python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, xbee

i want to continuously insert arduino serial Data in MySQL using Python.
I´ve already wrote a code. But only the first value is writing in mysql, by the second value, i get an error:"failed to get data from arduino". I hope somebody can help me and tell me what i´m doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import serial
import time
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys


#establish connection to MySQL. You'll have to change this for your database.
dbConn = mdb.connect("localhost","root","messung","voc-messung") or die ("could not connect to database")
#open a cursor to the database
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = 'COM7' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using


try:
print "Trying...",device
arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600)
except:
print "Failed to connect on",device
try:
while 2:
    time.sleep(2)
    data = arduino.readline()  #read the data from the arduino
    pieces = data.split("\t")  #split the data by the tab
    print pieces
        #Here we are going to insert the data into the Database
    try:
          #print 56  #verify the execution in the Try-loop
          cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO kammer_a (VOCWert) VALUES (%s)", (pieces[0]))
          print 5     #verify the execution in the Try-loop

          dbConn.commit() #commit the insert
          cursor.close()  #close the cursor
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
         print "failed to insert data"
    finally:
        cursor.close()  #close just incase it failed
except:
   print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

I´m using Python2.7.
The Arduino is connected to a Xbee module through Xbee shield  (coordinator in APi) and the other xbee is the router in AT mode

Comment: What's the exception thrown when you get the error?  What if there isn't data waiting for you?  Shouldn't you wrap your code in a check to see if there's serial data to read on the serial port before you actually try to read it?

Comment: i will try it and tell the result. thanks

Comment: hi tomlogic, i used while (20) with time sleep (20), but the data is not continuously insert in mysql.

Comment: i found a solution. I´ve put while true at the beginning of the code and it´s working fine now. The sensor value are inserting correctly every min in mysql.